# Continuity equation in the impeller of a centrifugal pump

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws

my question is about the consequence of the continuity equation in the impeller of a centrifugal pump. As the figure shows, the impeller spins with angular velocity $ \omega $. The fluid enters the impeller through A, and exits it through B. At A the impeller has tangential velocity U1, and at B tangential velocity U2. W1 and W2 are the relative velocities of the fluid with respect to the impeller at A and B respectively. And V1 and V2 are the absolute velocities. Now, V2 > V1, since the impeller accelerates the fluid. But my question is whether this would violate the continuity equation, since the area B is larger than A. Should the analysis of the continuity equation be done with W1 and W2 instead of V1 and V2. Would this mean that W1 > W2 always? Do the angles $ \alpha 1 $ and $ \beta 1 $ play a role?
Thanks for your help.
[image]

Comment: I deleted my response because i need a clarification: Where's the inlet and outlet of the pump?

Comment: The inlet is perpendicular to the page, as a cylinder with r1 radius. The outlet is not shown, but when the fluid leaves the impeller it impacts against a casing which redirects it to the outlet. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The clearances inside the impeller are not constant as you move from r1 to r2.  Because the fluid moves into a larger area as it moves away from the "eye" of the impeller, the clearances inside the impeller get smaller.  A proper impeller design will consider this, because this increase in area as the fluid flows towards r2 would cause cavitation inside the impeller if the continuity equation was ignored, and cavitation is very destructive to metal surfaces.

Comment: So this reduction in clearance compensates for the increase in transverse area? Which pair of velocities should be used for the continuity analysis? The absolute velocities, or the relative velocities? Thanks for your answer my friend.

Comment: @DavidEspinoza, I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve.  I'm telling you that the impeller design does not violate the continuity equation.  Given this fact, what further information are you looking for regarding velocities, and why are you looking for that information?

Comment: I understand, so without this decrease in clearance, cavitation would occur so that the continuity equation isnt violated right?

Comment: Correct ... the continuity equation isn't violated.